# Expired session cookie appears to still exist

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to delete a session cookie.  These are the steps I am following

```
        // Find the session - I believe this is doing a resume rather than starting a fresh session thus identifying the session.
        session_start();

        // Unset all the session variables enmasse by assigning an empty array
        $_SESSION = array();

        // find the session name that has been allocated then destroy the session cookie
        if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])){
            setcookie(session_name(),'', time()-42000, '/');
           // set content of found session to null, with a past time, at the root
        }

        // Destroy the session 
        session_destroy();
```

This definitely logs me out.  However the actual cookie still exists and can be viewed in the browser (firefox).

```
$_COOKIE[session_name()]
```

appears to be returning the encrypted content string as opposed to the session name.

Questions:

if $_COOKIE[session_name()] is not the correct way to get the session name what is?

Should I be setting a session_name instead of allowing it to default?

Am I seeing the session because it is waiting for some kind of garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

Based on that, you might want to be using `session_id()` as opposed to `session_name()`

Comment: Not so sure if that is correct, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: session_id is not working indeed it appears to return null. I am wondering if my reliance on root i.e. '/' is at fault rather than getting and using the cookie params

Comment: I had previously read this documentation but not applied it word of word. I have just tried doing so but it has not assisted.